# C++ Variadic Methods

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with undefined linker issues on Vardiac Methods only. I have already done an explicit instantiation of the template type as in:

```
template class CLASS<TYPE>;
```

This seems to adequately generate instantiations to the CTOR and DTOR of the class but doesn't seem to generate the variadic method public symbol. I use `nm | c++filter` to demangle and view names in the object module (.o) that explicitly declares the the `CLASS<TYPE>`.

I just want to confirm my suspicion that if you use templated class and variadic methods you absolutely need to include those methods in the header and have no option to include them in the .cpp.

Please note including the Variadic Methods in the header does in fact resolve the issue.

Comment: You can also instantiate template method in cpp for specific types; only those will be generated.

Comment: Do you have an explicit template instantiation *declaration* in the header? I.e. `extern template class CLASS<TYPE>; `

Comment: Do you have something like `template void CLASS<TYPE>::bar<TYPE2>(TYPE2&);`in cpp ?